# Wire front camera+sensors+display on SINGLE Ignition switched 12V wire

Tags: electrical, sensor, camera

I want to install front parking sensors & camera (+display). So I have:

1. Kit of 4 sensors + controller
2. Camera
3. Display

Basically I know how to install & wire them, the thing I don't sure is:

All 3 (camera, sensors & display) need constant 12V supply: Because they front I want them  always ON = Ignition switched. {Unlike reverse sensors that we need them only when reversed so they get power from reverse lights}.

So suppose I connect all 3 to the glovebox light (or any other SINGLE ignition switched wire) - Are there implications regarding overloading, short circuit etc? Because instead of 1 device (e.g. glovebox light) connected on that single ignition switched wire, now I will have 4: glovebox light+sensors+camera+display?

EDIT - Why I consist on single ignition switched 12V wire? Because I know how to find only 1 (the one of glovebox lights).

EDIT - Peugeot 508 (2013)

Thanks,

Comment: Well, unless the glovebox light always stays on in your car I suggest you use something else as the trigger. Knowing your vehicle's make, model and year may also be useful.

Comment: @michael - Presumably you have found that the glovebox light is switched by the 0v (ground) rather than the 12v.

Comment: @Zaid Thanks, I edited. The glovebox light has mechanical detection closing the lid. So anyway I have there ignition switched 12V wire. Another option is cigarette lighter. Any what about overloading of 4 on single wire?

Comment: @HandyHowie I don't understood what you meant.. Can you explain?

Comment: There will be a switch that controls the power to the light in the glove box, so that it only comes on when the door is open.  This switch could either be on the negative side of the battery (0v) or on the positive side of the battery (12v).  If it is on the 12v side, the bulb will not have 12v on it when you shut the door as @Zaid said.

Comment: @HandyHowie OK so let's say glovebox lights is not a good choice. So I switch to cigarette lighter. Anyway what about overloading of 4 instead of 1 on single wire source? Thanks,

Comment: You need to check the size of the fuse that supplies power to the circuit you want to use, then test how much current is used on that circuit when everything that uses it is on.  You will then know how much current you can draw for your devices before the fuse will blow.

Comment: @HandyHowie actually your last comment is answer... So I'll ask "stupid" question: In anyway I have protection from that fuse so I can't really damage whole car systems by that overloading. like worth case scenario is damaging that single circuit (which may be in charge of the radio and other stuff)?

Comment: Yes you're correct, you can't damage the rest of the car.  If you throw away the cigarette lighter element, you will have plenty of power for your devices.  You need to check if the cigarette lighter socket needs the ignition on to work.

Comment: @HandyHowie off course it's even must for safe work (I think it's ignition switched).

Comment: Another idea is to spread the four pieces across four different switched fuses and attach them at the fuse block. You shouldn't have any issues that way. You are kind of mixing thing sup a little bit, though ... in one part of your question you say the pieces need to be on all the time, yet you keep talking about "switched", which is NOT on all of the time. The glove box in most vehicles is built with an always on circuit.

Comment: @Paulster2 It is a good idea to spread the load, but I would suggest he stays away from the more essential circuits.  At least playing with the cigarette lighter circuit and possibly blowing its fuse won't have any affect on the rest of the car.